# Installing pam_radius through package manager

Tags: linux, centos, pam, radius

So instead of following the manual installation of pam_radius I installed EPEL and then got to install pam_radius using package manager :

```
yum --enablerepo=epel info pam_radius
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.wbs.co.za
 * epel: epel.scopesky.iq
 * extras: mirror.wbs.co.za
 * updates: mirror.wbs.co.za
Installed Packages
Name        : pam_radius
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.4.0
Release     : 2.el6
Size        : 55 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : PAM Module for RADIUS Authentication
URL         : http://www.freeradius.org/pam_radius_auth/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : pam_radius is a PAM module which allows user authentication using
            : a radius server.

Available Packages
Name        : pam_radius
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.4.0
Release     : 2.el6
Size        : 27 k
Repo        : epel
Summary     : PAM Module for RADIUS Authentication
URL         : http://www.freeradius.org/pam_radius_auth/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : pam_radius is a PAM module which allows user authentication using
            : a radius server.
```

I then looked for the file pam_radius_auth.so but I cant find it. I went to http://www.freeradius.org/pam_radius_auth/ and in the INSTALL folder it says:

```
  make.

  Copy 'pam_radius_auth.so' to /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so

  In /etc/pam.conf, add the line:

login   auth       sufficient   /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so

  AFTER

login   auth       required     /lib/security/pam_securetty.so

  and BEFORE

login   auth       required     /lib/security/pam_unix_auth.so

  i.e.

login   auth       required     /lib/security/pam_securetty.so
login   auth       sufficient   /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so
login   auth       required     /lib/security/pam_unix_auth.so
```

Now I am stuck, where do I go and do "make"....
Isn't the package manager supposed to all of the work?
Also there is a file pam_radius.conf is it there that I do the necessary configurations and thats all ??

How do I configure the pam client??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that those instructions are out of date, and mentioned an older PAM configuration file format. The two configuration lines in question should look like this:

```
auth required pam_securetty.so
auth required pam_unix.so
```

i.e. `pam_unix.so` instead of `pam_unix_auth.so`, and no full paths to the modules (just the actual module filename).

**Update**

As an aside, it seems that the `pam_unix` module used to be split into different modules for each purpose:

```
$ ls -l pam_unix*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    11 Jun 7  2010 pam_unix_acct.so -> pam_unix.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    11 Jun 7  2010 pam_unix_auth.so -> pam_unix.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    11 Jun 7  2010 pam_unix_passwd.so -> pam_unix.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    11 Jun 7  2010 pam_unix_session.so -> pam_unix.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 48824 Jun 7  2010 pam_unix.so
```

Comment: How do i go about the configuration then if there are files that are new, thanks.

Comment: Also when i do ls -l pam_unix* there is nothing ...

Comment: where you are checking `pam_unix` ?

Comment: you can refer to [this](https://docs.secureauth.com/display/81docs/PAM+RADIUS+Installation+and+Configuration+Guide) if this doesn't help you out.

Comment: Omg !!best answer ever sir, it works the link works thank you.

Comment: glad to know that. cheers